# In Java Windows Application using PdfBox Proguard zaps me

Tags: java, proguard

In a simple Java Windows Application using PdfBox Proguard zaps me.

My Java pgm has one class using PdfBox. Its essentials are:
    `import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException;`
    `import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;`
    `import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;`
    `import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;`
    `import org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition;`
    `public class PgmParser extends PDFTextStripper{. . .`

So far, my simple Proguard commands are:
    `-injars Pgm_Ant.jar`
    `-outjars Pgm_OSO.jar`
    `-libraryjars 'C:\Java\lib\rt.jar'`
    `-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\apache2\pdfbox-app-1.8.7.jar'`
    `-printmapping Pgm_OSO.map`
    `-keep public class pkgPgm.PgmMain {`
    `public static void main(java.lang.String[]);`
    `}`

I’ll appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Shrink, Obfuscate and Optimize my Java Pgm. It is, when Proguard tries to process the Java pgm gives me 1229 warning msgs. Apparently Proguard is also trying to Obfuscate the external jar file pdfbox.jar which is not needed to be processed.

Comment: Please edit your question to better reflect what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can add to the above: The command line used for the process is: java -jar proguard.jar @pgm_OSO.pro